# Form controls for Array of objects

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

```
{ 
    id: 123,
    email: "abc@gmail.com",
    password: 108,
    myObj:[
    { id:1, name:"abc", age: 20 },
    { id:2, name:"def", age: 21 },
    { id:3, name:"ghi", age: 22 },
    { id:4, name:"jkl", age: 23 } ] 
}
```

This is how I'm getting the fields from the server to patch, I'm patching them like this :

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    id: [],
    email: [],
    password: [],
    myObj: [] 
});
```

And I need each of `myObj` Array to be a separate form control.
I tried to access them from the HTML in different ways, (like `formControlName = myObj[0]` , `formControlName = myObj.name` 
) but no success..

How can I access `myObj` fields in the HTML?

Comment: `myObj` should be formArray, isn't it?

Comment: I tried something like this `this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    id: [],
    email: [],
    password: [],
    myObj: this.fb.array([])
});`  but then how do I access it from HTML? as I said `formControlName = myObj[0] ` and  `formControlName = myObj.name` doesn't work..

Answer (score 6):

it should be something like this:

```
objects: any[] = [];
myObj:[
    { id:1, name:"abc", age: 20 },
    { id:2, name:"def", age: 21 },
    { id:3, name:"ghi", age: 22 },
    { id:4, name:"jkl", age: 23 } ]

ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        id: [],
        email: [],
        password: [],
        objects: this.formBuilder.array([]) 
    }); 
this.objects = this.myForm.get('objects') as FormArray;
for(let obj of this.myOj){
    this.objects.push(this.createItem());
    }
}

createItem(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    id: '',
    name: '',
    age: ''
  });
}
```

and in template:

```
<div formArrayName="objects"
  *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('objects').controls; let i = index;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <input formControlName="id">
    <input formControlName="name">
    <input formControlName="age">
  </div>
</div>
```